# Unattended upgrades for dotnet not working

Tags: apt, upgrade, dotnet

I am trying to configre unattended-upgrades for microsoft dotnet on ubuntu 20.04.2.

I added the origin and section to allowed-origins in my unattended-upgrades config:

```
    Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
        "microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod:focal";
};
```

... and there are some dotnet upgrades waiting as reported by apt list --upgradeable:

```
aspnetcore-runtime-5.0/focal 5.0.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6-1]
dotnet-host/focal 5.0.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6-1]
dotnet-hostfxr-5.0/focal 5.0.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6-1]
dotnet-runtime-5.0/focal 5.0.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6-1]
dotnet-runtime-deps-5.0/focal 5.0.7-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.0.6-1]
```

... yet when I run sudo unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug, I get:

```
Checking: aspnetcore-runtime-5.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal' origin:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' label:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' site:'packages.microsoft.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: aspnetcore-runtime-5.0=5.0.6-1
Checking: dotnet-host ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal' origin:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' label:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' site:'packages.microsoft.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: dotnet-host=5.0.6-1
Checking: dotnet-hostfxr-5.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal' origin:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' label:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' site:'packages.microsoft.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: dotnet-hostfxr-5.0=5.0.6-1
Checking: dotnet-runtime-5.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal' origin:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' label:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' site:'packages.microsoft.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: dotnet-runtime-5.0=5.0.6-1
Checking: dotnet-runtime-deps-5.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal' origin:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' label:'microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod focal' site:'packages.microsoft.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: dotnet-runtime-deps-5.0=5.0.6-1
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
fetch.run() result: 0
Packages blacklist due to conffile prompts: []
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
The list of kept packages can't be calculated in dry-run mode.
```

Any ideas what the issue is? Why are the 5x dotnet packages not being upgraded?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the "origin" includes the release codename as well, as shown in the output of `unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug`:

> Checking: dotnet-hostfxr-6.0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic' origin:'microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod **bionic**' label:'microsoft-ubuntu-bionic-prod bionic' site:'packages.microsoft.com' isTrusted:True>])

(in my case it's "bionic" instead of "focal"). So instead of "microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod:focal" in `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` you need "microsoft-ubuntu-focal-prod **focal**:focal"

This should make it release-independent:

```
"microsoft-ubuntu-${distro_codename}-prod ${distro_codename}:${distro_codename}";
```